# Python - How can i remove a letter from a list of strings, change the strings to floats, transform some of the floats, and keep the order

Tags: python, string, list, loops, str-replace

```
myList=['57.43 N', '44.78 S', '59.64 S', '88.11 N']
```

I'm learning python, I have a list of strings representing `Lat/Lon`. I need to remove the `N/S` and when there is an `S` multiply by `-1`, and have all strings converted to `floats`. I was thinking I could build an index of my values, and somehow separate the strings with S from the ones with N, create North and South lists remove the N/S with,

```
x=[x.remove('NS') for x in myList]
y=[y.remove('S') for x in myList]
```

multiply the y list by -1 and use extend x by y so my index stays in tact. Any advice would be very lovely. 
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You seem to have a solution.

Comment: Do not use side-effects in a list.

Comment: Do you want your output to be two lists i.e. of `N` and `S` as follows?
`[57.43, 88.11]` and `[-44.78, -59.64]` given `myList`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehensions to achieve this succinctly:

```
newList = [-1 * float(x[:-2]) if 'S' in x else float(x[:-2]) for x in mylist]
```

Of course, this assumes the following about each of your elements:

1. The last two characters are always `' N'` or `' S'`.
2. The other characters can be converted into floats.

Answer (score 0):

You can just split each string into number and direction. If the direction is `S`, multiply it by `-1`:

```
myList=['57.43 N', '44.78 S', '59.64 S', '88.11 N']

result = []
for data in myList:
    num, direction = data.split()

    num = float(num)
    if direction == 'S':
        num *= -1

    result.append(num)

print(result)
# [57.43, -44.78, -59.64, 88.11]
```